# Android: Filter intent for specific Uri pattern

Tags: android, filter, android-activity, android-intent, pattern-matching

I need my Android application to run a certain Activity in my app, responding to the following Uri data from the Intent that was sent out:

http://www.example.com/redirect.aspx?customurl=example%3a%2f%2f%3fop%3dexampledetail%26stuff%3d12345%26morestuff%3dI%2520Love%25Android

If I use the following in my manifest (for the Activity that I want to respond to the Intent), I can capture this, but the chooser pops up (which I don't want):

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Since I don't want the chooser to pop up, I tried to use the android:pathPattern, or android:pathPrefix in the  tag to further filter to make sure that only my app responds but it isn't working for me.

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: I'm only posting this as a comment, not an answer, since I'm really just speculating (I haven't done any Android programming yet), but I'd think that you'll always get the chooser if there's another app that can respond to the same intent (notably the browser, in your case) until the user says "always use this one". Perhaps using a custom URI scheme would avoid this?

Comment: That's what I am assuming would be accomplished by the pathPattern or pathPrefix.

Comment: A specific URI scheme does indeed solve the issue, unfortunately I have to deal with DoubleClick so the scheme absolutely MUST be http.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your dealing with data which comes from your own application, so don't use your "private" URL as the target of the intent but create a component specific Intent and give it the URL of your data as an EXTRA parameter.

Something like:

```
Uri privateUri = Uri.parse("http://yourserver.com/path/to/data");
Intent i = new Intent(context, yourActivity.class);
i.putExtra("DATA_URI", privateUri);
startActivity(i);
```

In yourActivity.class, you would just have to get the Uri with the following code:

```
Uri privateUri = (Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("DATA_URI");
```

Comment: The data actually doesn't come from my application, it comes from an Ad SDK, which creates an implicit Intent with the VIEW action when a specific ad is clicked. I'm trying to bypass the chooser and handle the Intent in my application.

Comment: If you're not the originator of the intent, you won't be able to do that. All intents with ACTION_VIEW and http scheme should be presented to the user with the choice of a browser. As introduced by CommonsWare, letting apps seemlessly intercept http intents would be a huge security hole, allowing to replace payment or bank (for example) URL calls with malicious software.

Answer (score 7):

> If I use the following in my manifest (for the Activity that I want to respond to the Intent), I can capture this, but the chooser pops up (which I don't want):

Most Android devices will have 1+ browsers on them. The user is perfectly welcome to visit that URL in one of those browsers instead of your app, which is why the chooser appears. Moreover, it would be a massive security hole if developers were able to hijack any HTTP URL they wanted.

Now, if you own the Web site for which this URL links to, you can use the trick that Barcode Scanner uses: use browser detection to put smarts on that page that, if viewed in an Android browser, explains to the user why they should allow your app to handle that URL in the future.

Comment: This is a custom URL that nobody will browse to. It's just data that is passed to an intent in the form of a URL.

Comment: @Scienceprodigy: Then why are you using an HTTP URL, if it's not really an HTTP URL?

Comment: @Scienceprodigy: I don't know what you are trying to do beyond your question. What you are trying to can obviously be done, as you said you did it in your question. However, the user will get the chooser. That is unavoidable if you use an HTTP URL. If it is "just data that is passed to an Intent in the form of a URL", then don't use an HTTP URL. Use a less contentious option, like an `intent` URL. See http://commonsware.com/sample (third bullet) and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler/ for an example.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Short answer is I'm dealing with DoubleClick and they won't accept a custom scheme, it has to be http.

Comment: Scienceprodigy: I'll put it this way: how should the OS know a-priori that your URL isn't something that should be browsed to, but instead should be handled by your app? It's a regular HTTP URL as far as it knows

Comment: @Scienceprodigy: Then, no, what you want is probably not possible, at least without the chooser. Bear in mind it might also violate DoubleClick's terms of service, since I would have to think they will look askance at anything blocking clicks on their ads.

Comment: The ad campaign is mine, so this would be for a specific ad, which I want to resolve to an activity in my app. DoubleClick requires the http scheme, hence my dilemma. If they let me specify a custom scheme, my problem will vanish.

Comment: @Scienceprodigy: "so this would be for a specific ad" -- not with that URL syntax it wouldn't. The stuff that is unique to you is not in the path, but in parameters, which are not filterable in any case in Android.