# Android: What is the purpose of android:pathPattern if I can't filter http scheme?

Tags: android, api, android-intent, pattern-matching

I want to capture Intents with a specific Uri pattern that uses the http scheme. I DO NOT want the chooser dialog to pop up.

The Android API advertises filtering of intents based on pattern matching of the path part of the Uri:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

However, when I try to specify a pattern for my path other than ".*" (which pops up the chooser, which I'm trying to avoid), it doesn't work, and the browser automatically handles the Intent.

So, my question is, what is the purpose of the pathPattern/pathPrefix if, for the http scheme, it either auto resolves to the browser, or pops up the chooser anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to capture Intents with a specific Uri pattern that uses the http scheme. I DO NOT want the chooser dialog to pop up.

And, [as I told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110515/android-filter-intent-for-specific-uri-pattern), that is not possible, as that would be a security hole.

> However, when I try to specify a pattern for my path other than ".*" (which pops up the chooser, which I'm trying to avoid), it doesn't work, and the browser automatically handles the Intent.

[Here is an example](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#b2bXTFUfX1o/AndroidManifest.xml&q=package:android%20pathPrefix%20lang:xml&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc) of a pattern, more than a simple wildcard, that presumably works.

> So, my question is, what is the purpose of the pathPattern/pathPrefix if, for the http scheme, it either auto resolves to the browser, or pops up the chooser anyways?

So that you can be an option in the chooser for the right subset of stuff. In the case of the Calendar application I linked to above, it would be silly for the Calendar to appear in the chooser for arbitrary URLs -- it only knows how to handle certain Google Calendar URLs. Hence, they put in the filter, so they are only appear in relevant contexts.

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to allow filtering, one would assume to be able to filter at a level to which you would be the only app available to handle the intent, thus bypassing the chooser.

Comment: @Scienceprodigy, but you are *not* the only app available to handle the intent. The browser can also handle it, because it is less restrictive.

Comment: @Scienceprodigy: What part of "this is a security hole" are you not understanding?